# Cheapest way to host MongoDB on Azure

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

We have been developing a RESTful web api using node and MongoDB. For hosting options, we decided to use Azure through BizSpark. We used DocumentDB with protocol support for MongoDB.

The problem now is DocumentDB is consuming all the credit causing a downtime and we haven't started making money yet. We are now considering switching from DocumentDB to MongoDB. The question now becomes, what is the cheapest way to host MongoDB on Azure?

So far on our research, we have found two options:

1. Using a VM (Linux or Windows)
2. Using a worker role

Please advice if there are other options, and how easy can it be to switch between these options at a later stage.

Comment: This is really broad and off-topic. That said: You never shared how you built out your DocumentDB database, type of collections, number of collections, scale of collections, etc. All those choices directly impact your DocumentDB cost footprint. And as for MongoDB on a VM: You can easily figure out the pricing yourself on that, based on Azure's pricing documentation on VM costs, size + number of VMs, and type of storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Azure` calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) to get estimates between `DocumentDB` and a VM with the settings your company needs to see which one is cheaper.

If you are using Bizspark, remember that you have 5 accounts in which you can distribute all your costs to optimize in a better way.

**Personal recommendations(subjective view):**

1. Remember that if you are using the `PAAS` solution(`DocumentDB`) you
   get full functionality out of the box, you don't have to set it up
   and you can escale it very easily and plug in to very powerful tools
   like `PowerBi` out of the box.
2. In the case of `IAAS` solution(vms) you have to install, mantain and
   create all the connection settings for this to work. If you want to
   scale you have to me more dedicated, since you have to scale it
   through the use of more vms, traffic managers and more robust
   architecture. If this is the path you are taking I would recommend
   using containers like `Docker` inside the VM and their power to
   manage this.

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot that I have 5 accounts.

Comment: This isn't an answer. This is pointing out a few differences between PaaS and IaaS (with opinions about containers thrown in). There is absolutely no way to know which is more cost-effective for the OP: We have no business requirements, there's been no benchmarking, we don't know about HA/DR/geo-replication needs, on and on. Not sure why this was marked as an accepted answer.

Comment: Edited the answer to make it more straight forward, thanks for the feedback.